# Parsing String to Double including scientific notation E

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I use `Choco` constraint solver to solve a problem.
I use `RealVariable`s `x`, `y` and `z`.
The solution looks like this

```
x[3.9999999999999996, 4.000000000000001]
y[-3.1434555694057773E-162, 3.1434555694057773E-162]
z[-3.1434555694057773E-162, 3.1434555694057773E-162]
```

And I try to parse the solutions to double variables.

Here is my code:

```
String X = s.getVar(x).toString();
String Y = s.getVar(y).toString();
String Z = s.getVar(z).toString();

Matcher match = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?").matcher(X);
while(match.find())
{
     double d = Double.parseDouble(match.group());
     System.out.println("value= " + d);
}
match = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?").matcher(Y);
while(match.find())
{
     DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00"); 
     Double d = Double.parseDouble(match.group());
     System.out.println("value= " + format.format(d));
}
match = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?").matcher(Z);
while(match.find())
{
     double d = Double.parseDouble(match.group());
     System.out.println("parsed: " + d);
}
```

The output is:

```
parsed: 3.9999999999999996
parsed: 4.000000000000001
parsed: -3,14
parsed: -162,00
parsed: 3,14
parsed: -162,00
parsed: -3.143455569405777
parsed: -162.0
parsed: 3.143455569405777
parsed: -162.0
```

Which means, `-162` is parsed like another double. How do I prevent this? How can I parse a `String` to `Double` using scientific notation?

Does this happen because `E-162` is too long for `Double`?

Comment: `E` doesn't match your regex, so it finds 4 matches on both `y` and `z`. You need to take into account the number might have an `E`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your pattern to take account of the exponant:

```
Matcher match = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?(E-?\\d+)?").matcher(X);
```

*Note: The capturing groups are not needed here, you can replace them by non-capturing groups `(?:...)`.*

Since you will use the same regex several times, it is better to define the pattern once and for all, instead of repeating `Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?(E-?\\d+)?")`. You can use this:

```
static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:E-?\\d+)?");
....
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(X);
....
match = pattern.matcher(Y);
....
match = pattern.matcher(Z);
```

Answer (score 3):

`Double#parseDouble` parses `double`s from `String`s *and* it parses the exponet aswell.

`System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("1.2345e5"));`

--> 123450.0

Example: https://ideone.com/ACTVQT

Answer (score 1):

To catch all numbers in Java from regex use this pattern

```
"-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?(E-?\\d+)?(E\\+?\\d+)?(E?\\d+)?(e-?\\d+)?(e\\+?\\d+)?(e?\\d+)?"
```

I have tried this regex on following strings and all of them returned `true`

```
"2546546516",
"-2546546516",
"2546546516.1241546",
"-2546546516.415441",
"2.5465E+09",
"-2.5465E+09",
"2.5465E-09",
"-2.5465E-09",
"2.5465e+09",
"-2.5465e+09",
"2.5465e-09",
"-2.5465e-09",
"445.4e2",
"-445.4e2"
```

Note: This answer was inspired by Casimir's answer

PS. Edits are welcome